# Linking already-linked facebook/twitter accounts with PFUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I want to share content by means of social media. I have found that for me, the simplest strategy is to link the social media account with the PFUser. Once linked, the publishing of content is simple and works terrific.

My problem arises when a user is trying to publish with a social media account already linked to another user. The case is the same for both twitter and facebook. Here’s what happens:
- I am presented with the login form, and enter the login information of the facebook/twitter account already linked to another PFUser.
- I get the expected reply: that the operation failed.
- I try to go again, wanting to specify a different facebook/twitter account.
- The account is assumed by parse, and I get the same reply without entering any credentials.

I am not allowed to try with a different social-media account?!? Logging out the PFUser does not work - I actually have to delete the app entirely.

... Yes, I expect people to have several social-media accounts (or maybe rather, different social-media accounts may share PFUsers...)

Help is greatly appreciated!

- A